# what is the best way to build chat between two authenticated users in laravel?

Tags: laravel

what is the best way to build chat between two authenticated users in laravel?

Comment: Opinion based and broad questions are both off-topic here at Stackoverflow.  Read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

This is a very general question. But you can use `Pusher` and `Laravel mix` to build a real-time chat app. You can find some detailed tutorials searching on google.